# How to get a DataSource during initialization of a WebLogic application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, weblogic, javabeans

I'm using WebLogic with Spring, talking to an Oracle DB. I've setup a Servlet that implements ServletContextListener, and configured the web.xml to add the class as a listener. In the call to contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce), I'm trying to get a DataSource object that i've configured in a bean in my application.xml, so that I can do some stuff with the DB when the application starts up.

```
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {
      InitialContext enc = new InitialContext();
      Context compContext = (Context) enc.lookup("java:comp/env");
      dataSource = (DataSource) compContext.lookup("dataSource");
      ...
```

This throws a NameNotFoundException on the lookup. How should I be getting this?
my bean looks like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory"
      factory-method="getPoolDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"/>
    <property name="connectionPoolName" value="COS_POOL"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: You don't. Why would you need a servlet listener to this...

Comment: I'm just trying to find a way to do some DB stuff on application startup. Maybe using a servlet is the wrong approach. If so, what is the right approach?

Comment: Use a spring `ApplicationListener` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation in one of the Spring Managed beans to perform operations you want during application start up. Alternatively you can implement `InitializingBean` and implement `afterPropertiesSet` method.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do, as there is no guarantee that proxies are already created and when needing a transaction or other resource management that might not work yet. Better is to use an `ApplicationListener` and listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent`s.